# How to get from hashmap into a list?

Tags: clojure

How do I construct a clojure sequence in which some elements are values of a map? In the below code, I expect to get the following list: `("hi" "there" "Bob")`. But it seems that the outer quote on the list prevents the inner function from evaluating, but removing the quote attempts to evaluate the raw string result of the inner function as the outer function. Why doesn't using an outer quote work and what's the appropriate way to accomplish this?

```
koan-engine.runner=> (def person {:name "Bob"})
#'koan-engine.runner/person
koan-engine.runner=> (:name person)
"Bob"
koan-engine.runner=> '("hi" "there" (:name person))
("hi" "there" (:name person))
koan-engine.runner=> ("hi" "there" (:name person))
Execution error (ClassCastException) at koan-engine.runner/eval2100 (form-init7624891432873678129.clj:1).
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```